# Como puedo obtener la longitud del contenido de un HANLDE?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Necesito hacer un programa en [c](/questions/tagged/c) que copie el contenido de un archivo en otro archivo. Estoy usando objetos `HANDLE` para abrir el archivo de origen y de destino y estoy usando `DWORD` para leer el contenido. El código es el siguiente

```
HANDLE hIn = CreateFile("testSource.txt", FILE_READ_DATA, 0 , NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
HANDLE hOut = CreateFile("testTarget.txt", FILE_WRITE_DATA, 0 , NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
char buf[30] = {'\0'};

if(hIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("No existe alguno de los archivos\n");
} else
{
    DWORD readText;
    ReadFile(hIn, buf, 36, &readText, NULL);
    WriteFile(hOut, buf, 36, &readText, NULL);
}

CloseHandle(hIn);
CloseHandle(hOut);
```

El problema es que las funciones `ReadFile` y `WriteFile` necesitan tener el tamaño que se quiere leer o que se quiere escribir. ¿Como puedo obtener la cantidad de caracteres que contiene el objeto `HANDLE` del archivo que escribí para poder indicar cuantos caracteres voy a escribir en el archivo de destino?

Comment: ¿La pregunta es `C` o `C++`?

Comment: "Estoy usando objetos HANDLE para abrir el archivo de origen y de destino..." Esta oración no tiene sentido. Deberías leer la documentación de esas funciones.

Answer (score 1):

La función [`GetFileSizeEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364957(v=vs.85).aspx) te permite obtener el tamaño de un archivo, en bytes, pasándole el `HANDLE`.

Pero si todo lo que quieres es copiar el contenido de un archivo, usando la API de Windows, quizás te convenga llamar [`CopyFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx) directamente.